# Float numbers in ERB/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, floating-point, erb

I'm pretty new to Rails, I'm passing 2 variables to a view, in my controller have them defined like

```
@correct = 5
@total = 40
```

in my view I'm trying to mark them up like:

```
Score = <%=@score%>/<%=@total%> = <%=(@score/@total)%>
```

It outputs 0 for the division. Do I need to explicitly define that equation to output a float or something? How do I get it to output 0.125 instead of 0

Thanks guys

Comment: In ruby, When you do arithmetic with integers, you'll get integer answers. And if you want to get a float or decimal number then at least one of the divisor or dividend must be decimal/float.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decide whether you want to use `@correct` or `@score`. Also to use double division instead of integer multiply `@score` by `1.0`:

```
<%=(1.0 * @score/@total)%>
```

Or alternatively cast `@score` to float:

```
<%=(@score.to_f/@total)%>
```

Comment: Thanks man, I had a bit of brain lapse there re: var name! :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly convert your integers into floats:

```
1.9.3p0 :001 > a = 5
 => 5 
1.9.3p0 :002 > b = 40
 => 40 
1.9.3p0 :003 > a / b
 => 0 
1.9.3p0 :005 > (a / b).to_f
 => 0.0 
1.9.3p0 :006 > a.to_f / b.to_f
 => 0.125
```

In your case:

```
Score = <%=@score%>/<%=@total%> = <%=(@score.to_f/@total.to_f)%>
```

Comment: actually casting just `@score` will suffice